# Before the sin, would it have been possible to be murdered?

Tags: death, sin, adam

We know that before the chet (sin) of the eating of the forbidden fruit, mankind would not physically expire and die. (Death was the punishment given for the sin - B'reishis 3:19, Shabbos 55, Ramban 2:17). What about other death? Examples would include murder (let's assume unintentional) by metal, fire, ice, or falling from great heights, or drowning. I would surmise that a person would have been able to die in such forms. But does anyone have any source for this? (Either to support or reject.) All sources I'm aware of speak of "misa" - "death" in general. I don't know if they'd include a broader definition of these forms of death.

(Let me just preempt - if you're thinking of B'rachos 33a with R' Chanina ben Dosa, I don't think it's really a raya - see Rashi, really based on Yerushalmi.)

Comment: Do you mean to ask specifically whether someone could've become a murder victim? Because it seems you can generalize this to any unnatural form of death (drowning, falling off a cliff, etc.).

Comment: Before the chait people would have not fallen prey to the sin of murder.

Comment: I've heard that before the advent of Da'at, man couldn't conceive of a possibility of choice beyond the givens of what the garden consisted of. True free will consists of total license to conceive of new realities, and so prior to the sin Man was unable to imagine a possibility beyond the given set, which would preclude murder.

Comment: I've edited my question according to your comments, thank you!

Comment: Rashi's understanding of the story of Kayin and Hevel is that they were born before the cheit and implies that they did NOT eat of the fruit - it says Adam and Chava made all the animals eat, not their children (who were around according to Rashi). Kayin was exiled FROM EDEN as a result of killing Hevel, so according to Rashi, it would seem that man was "mortal" in that he could be killed, but biologically would have lived forever absent the sin of eating from the tree.  I've got a lot more about this understanding of Bereishis, but it's not relevant for answering this question...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Thanks so much for your comment. I only hesitate to take it as proof-positive for the question. The reason is because the Rashi (and the midrash that he's quoting) about giving the other animals of the fruit isn't contextually speaking about the subject of my question, but rather merely who ate from the fruit. While it's true that Kayin and Hevel are not mentioned in the Rashi or in the Chazal, it may be simply because that's not the subject; and if we communicate that even the animals ate, certainly their kids were given, as well. (TBC below)

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I’m not embracing this deflection, just positing that it’s there to be made. In summation – I think what you wrote is a brilliant “diyuk”, but I wouldn’t call it an outright source. Thank you so much for your time to respond!

Comment: @Talmid That's why I didn't post as an answer, I have strong inferences and diyuk, but little definitive proof. I will note that IF Kayin  and Hevel had eaten from the tree then they should have been expelled like Adam was, but the language is very explicit that ONLY Adam and eve were kicked out of the garden... so coupled with Rashi stating that they already had children (harbeh  arbeh also implies "more than it was previously"). But again, he never says it explicitly.